# How to insert date of dirth directly into my database table

Tags: c#, mysql

My question is there any data type is there in MySQL to insert date of birth into the database table directly else which data type i can choose to insert date of birth into the table?

Comment: Dirth - the day darth vader was born

Comment: did you try something already or you just want someone to do this for you?

Comment: What is a "date of dirth"? If you want help here, at least put forth the effort to proof-read your own question before posting. Assuming you actually meant "date of birth", there is no special data type for a date of birth; it's a date. I'm certain a quick Google or Bing search on MySQL+Date will find relevant information. SO should be the *last resort* for getting an answer to a question, not the first.

Comment: @zoran404 i tried already with var char(50).

Comment: don't use varchar for dates, unless you're going to use it simply as test. if you want to do something with it then use DATE dadatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), so use the data type *[DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)*

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DATE` datatype. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html the `DATE` type is distinct from `DATETIME` in that it ignores the time. You must use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format in your `INSERT` OR `UPDATE` SQL if you're not using parameters (which you should be).

```
CREATE TABLE People (
    dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO People ( dateOfBirth ) VALUES ( '1966-07-01' )
```

Comment: I'm a great believer in `dateOfBirth DATE NULL`. This is a matter of personal experience with unappropriate `dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL` that did lead to bad data in some databases ...

Comment: @VMai it depends on his business requirements. I included the `NOT NULL` modifier so the OP doesn't forget to be stringent in his column definitions.